# How to force max() to break a tie when comparing integer values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, max

I have four integer variables like so:

```
a = 3 
b = 1
c = 0
d = 3
```

I put them into a dictionary like so:

```
big_number = {'a': a, 'b': b,\
                  'c': c, 'd': d}
```

I want to pick the variable associated with the greatest integer value.

I try picking the greatest integer value like so:

```
winner = max(big_number, key=big_number.get)
```

There are two problems:

```
 1. winner is only choosing first variable with the greatest value when there is tie with multiple variables. 
 2. I dont know how detect and break the tie if one happens.
```

I want to force the `winner` variable if a tie occurs to be set too `d`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why `d`? How did you choose that key?

Comment: @Selcuk `d` is an example, I want a flexible solution, that if a tie occurs between the 4 variables, I want to force the choice to be `d`. Once again this an example

Comment: Instead of using `max` use `sorted` and check if the first and the second elements are the same. If they are, there is a tie.

Comment: @Selcuk could you please give me an example? Also I want to check any two variables, so is there a fast way to check all possibilities? Hope that makes sense. Thank you for helping!

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a compact 'pythonic' way to do this, but you can do it by looping through the dictionary like so:

```
a = 3 
b = 1
c = 0
d = 3

big_number = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}

hival=None
hikey=None
tie=False
for key in big_number:
    val=big_number[key]
    if(hival is None or val>hival):
        hikey=key
        hival=val
        tie=False
    elif(val==hival):
        tie=True

if(tie):
    print('tie')
else:
    print('hikey:', hikey, 'hival:', hival)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `max` use `sorted` and check if the first and the second elements are the same. If they are, there is a tie:

```
big_number = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 3}
default = 'b'
sorted_numbers = sorted(big_number, key=big_number.get)
if big_number[sorted_numbers[-1]] == big_number[sorted_numbers[-2]]:
    print(default)
else:
    print(sorted_numbers[-1])
```

If you are not interested in the top 2 and want to check if there are any duplicate values, you can compare the length of the dict and the `set()` of its values:

```
if len(big_number) != len(set(big_number.values())):
    print(default)
else:
    # do something else...
```